# Iterative MergeSort Time Complexity (Bottom-Up)

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

I have a problem with finding the time-complexity.

- Firtly, speaking about the outer FOR in MergeSort, i think that the repetitions are (1+ Sumation(from i=1, to sizeOfArray)(2*i) = 1+(2+4+8+16+32+...+size) but i also think that i am very wrong.
- I also have a problem measuring the inside FOR-loop repetitions.

**MergeSort**(){     //Iterative Version (Bottom-Up)

```
            for(int currentSize = 1; currentSize < length; currentSize *= 2)        {
                for(int low = 0; low < length - currentSize; low += 2*currentSize){

                    int mid = low + currentSize - 1;
                    //min() is used here so if low is very close to the end of the array, high doesn't take outOfBoundries Value.
                    int high = Math.min(low + currentSize*2 -1, length - 1);

                }
            }
```

}

**merge**(int low, int middle, int high) {

```
            // Copy both parts into the helper array
            for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
                    helper[i] = arrayForMergeSort[i];
            }

            int i = low;
            int j = middle + 1;
            int k = low;
            // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
            // to the original array
            while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
                    if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {

                            arrayForMergeSort[k] = helper[i];
                            i++;
                    } else {

                            arrayForMergeSort[k] = helper[j];
                            j++;
                    }
                    k++;
            }
            // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
            while (i <= middle) {
                    arrayForMergeSort[k] = helper[i];
                    k++;
                    i++;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the outer loop, the number of iterations is ceil(log2(length)).

For the inner loop, the number of runs to be merged on each iteration is ceil(length / currentSize) or floor((length + currentSize - 1) / currentSize). If this is an even number, then the last run's size may be less than currentSize. If this is an odd number, then the last run has no run to merge with and also may be less than currrentSize. I'm not sure there's a way to calculate the total number of merge operations without using iteration to sum the merge operations per iteration.

In a "production" version of merge sort, a one time allocation of a working array the same (or 1/2) the size of the original array is done, and then the direction of merge (original to working or working to original is changed with each outer loop. If the program pre-caculates the number of outer iterations, and it is an odd number, then a pre-pass can be done to swap elements in place on the initial pass, so that an even number of merge passes are done, with the sorted data ending up in the original array.

Comment: So i finaly found expirementaly that the repetitions of outer for-loop are C(n) = log(n).   And the inner for-loop does n/log(n) repetitions so we have a total of n repetitions. Correct me if im wrong. So we have n repetitions of the merge function that runs in Theta(n). So what is the total complexity?

Comment: Assuming a typical merge sort, the inner loop always moves n elements on each iteration, so the total number of moves is (inner times outer loop) n log(n). The worst case number of compares per inner loop is n-1, the best case if merging two runs of size n/2 is n/2 compares, so big O time complexity for the compares is O(n log(n)), since the constants are ignored.